# Programmatically submit form set with dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to submit a form after the data is received as serialized HTML from a higher component where I'm calling an API that server side render a form.

Is there any way to do this, as I have tried in all known methods by me, windows.onload = ...(ById("submit").submit() ; componentDidUpdate ; as callback after createMarkup..

I am newbie in React and if the above condition make impossible to call submit please let me know.

Thank you!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const ServerSideForm = (props) => {
  const [html, setHtml] = useState(props.data);

  const style = {
    display: 'none'
  };

  // useState(props)
  console.log('props', html);

  function createMarkup(props) {
    return { __html: props };
    // cb();
  }

  return <div style={style} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(html)}></div>;
  //
};

export default ServerSideForm;
```

Comment: [`useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook can be used to execute the code after a render. The function passed to `useEffect` will run after the render is committed to the screen. By default, effects run after every completed render, but you can choose to fire them only when certain values have changed.

Comment: Already tried a conditional in useEffect(), not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook can be used to execute the code after a render.

Assuming that `data` prop supplied to `ServerSideForm` changes from empty string `''` to HTML text bellow and form name is `myform`:

```html
<form action="/action" method="POST" name="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" value="value1" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" value="value2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

`ServerSideForm` can use `useEffect` to submit `myform` form when it's loaded and rendered:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const ServerSideForm = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.data.length) { // only when 'data' is loaded
            if (document.forms['myform']) { // when form is present
                document.forms['myform'].submit();
            }
        }
    });

    const style = {
        display: 'none'
    };

    return <div style={style} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: props.data
    }}></div>;
};

export default ServerSideForm;
```

Comment: Thank you, I have finally solve it. The issue was that in the superior componend I need to put a conditional rendering for this component in order to not be charged into DOM until the data is received from the API also an issue was that the React app was crushing because of .length applied over an undefined  props.data, so I have put it into a try catch block.

Answer (score 1):

As @Vitalii said, useEffect is what is needed here, it just needs to be used correctly to monitor changes in props.data.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const ServerSideForm = (props) => {
  const [html, setHtml] = useState(props.data);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHtml(props.data);
  }, [props.data]);
  const style = {
    // display: "none" //This hides your html
  };

  // useState(props)
  console.log("props", html);

  function createMarkup(props) {
    return { __html: props };
    // cb();
  }

  return <div style={style} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(html)}></div>;
};
export default ServerSideForm;
```

Full working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-morning-5l5e1?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

In order to select elements in your html you need to wait for it to be rendered and then execute a querySelector to access the submit button, you can achieve it with useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // This code allows you to execute code after render (return) like querySelector or whatever
  submitButton = document.querySelector(".submitButton");
}, [props.data]);
```

Second, the following code isn't necessary:

```
const [html, setHtml] = useState(props.data);


function createMarkup(props) {
  return { __html: props };
  // cb();
}
```

Your final code may look like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const ServerSideForm = (props) => {
  let submitButton;

  const style = {
    display: 'none'
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    submitButton = document.querySelector(".submit");
    // Here you can do whatever you want with the "submit button"
  }, [props.data]);

  function createMarkup(htmlString) {
    return { __html: htmlString };
    // cb();
  }

  return <div style={style} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={props.data}></div>;
  // This this option is also correct
  // return <div style={style} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(data)}></div>;
};

export default ServerSideForm;
```

Probably the value of submit button gets lost at some point when re-rendering or maybe you need to execute something on each re-render, then you can remove the second parameter from useEffect and your code would look like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
        
const ServerSideForm = (props) => {
  let submitButton;
  
  const style = {
    display: 'none'
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    submitButton = document.querySelector(".submit");
    if (submitButton) {
      // Here you can do whatever you want with the "submit button"
    }
  });
  
  function createMarkup(htmlString) {
    return { __html: htmlString };
    // cb();
  }
  
  return <div style={style} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={props.data}></div>;
  // This this option is also correct
  // return <div style={style} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(data)}></div>;
  };
  
export default ServerSideForm;
```

Here is a clean example https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-ellis-lxfxz